# How to run migration in RabbitMQ with symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, console, rabbitmq, command

Hi I want to run migration file as a background task using RabbitMQ  in symfony
but when i do the migration execution in console commands is waiting state.

when i press ctrl+c and trying to stop the consumer the migration starts executing
 Please help me

```
$command = array(
            'command' => 'doctrine:migrations:execute',
            '--em' => "dynamic",
            'version' => $this->container->getParameter('migration_version')
        );


            $kernel = $this->getContainer()->get('kernel');
            $application = new Application($kernel);
            $application->setAutoExit(false);
            $input = new ArrayInput($command);
            $output = new BufferedOutput();
            $result = $application->run($input, $output);
            $s=$output->fetch();
```

I tried this please help me used

php-amqplib/rabbitmq-bundle

This symfony bundle

I think because of 2 background processes rabbirmq consumer and console command migration running

Comment: I am sorry, but I can't follow you. Is the above code snippet what is being executed when the message from the queue is processed? If so how is this code called? Can you maybe do a step by step description how you trigger the message and how it is processed, this also might help understand what the issue and a possible solution is.

Comment: When the message comes in queue it start processing. But migration is not running

Comment: How are you processing the queue? Are you using a library like Enqueue or Symfony Messenger? Is it a cron job that is running or do you run the consume-command manually? If so have tried using a more verbose output using the option `-vvv` to check if there are exceptions or other errors?

Comment: I use rabbitmq for background task. It processes all the other tasks other than migration execution given a obove when the message comes

Comment: RabbitMQ is just the message broker. It keeps the messages, but does not process them by itself. How do you receive (= process) the messages from the queue?

Comment: I use terminal command to run the consumer. When i send message from controller it starts receicing the meaaage and starts procesaing

Comment: What console command are you running and what is the output? Please add this to your question.

Comment: use OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\RabbitMq\ConsumerInterface;class AttachmentsConsumer implements ConsumerInterface

Comment: I used the command php bin/console consumer:consumername

Comment: If I read the documentation right, it should be `bin/console rabbitmq:consumer <consumer_name>`. What is the output you get when you run your command, preferrably with the `-vvv` option, so `bin/console consumer:consumername -vvv`?

Comment: Its in waiting state. When i press ctrl+c it starts migrating. I think console command is also a background process 2 processes running simultaniously when 1 stops the other starts working

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't used that bundle before and without proper output I can't see what the issue is. Maybe you should add the information (the bundle you use and what command you are running) to the question to make it easier for others to help you. You might also want to check the bundle's issue tracker to see if this is a known problem or maybe ask for help there.

Comment: Its not the bundles issue i think.. the symfony migration the only thing that wont work other things are working fine. Please help me sir updated the qn with bundle used

Comment: Have you tried to run the migration without using RabbitMQ? It might be that the command is asking for some user input, which won't work when it is executed automatically. For example I do not see an `--no-interaction` option in your command example. This suppresses asking for manual confirmation and could be what is causing the issue. Again without output it is hard to tell and only guess work.

Comment: When i run the migration in controller it works fine. With the above code given. The problem is running via consumer

Comment: Can you share the no interaction code i will mark you green tick if it works

Answer (score 1):

When running a migration it will ask for user input, to confirm the migration. This is because, tables might be changed which could lead to data loss. This is also why this operation should not be run in production.

In order to make this command work automatically, without user intervention, as would be required when running it as part of processing a queue message, you have to add an additional option. In your example it could look like this:

```
$command = array(
    'command' => 'doctrine:migrations:execute',
    '--no-interaction' => null,
    '--em' => "dynamic",
    'version' => $this->container->getParameter('migration_version')
);

// same as in your code snippet
```

The additional option should prevent your command from being interrupted. If this still does not help consider increasing the error output by adding another option `-vvv` for additional debug information in a similar way to the array.